# Continuous ping on google's servers

Tags: windows, google, wireshark, icmp

Using Wireshark, I recently discovered that my computer (running on Windows 10) is sending ping requests to Google's servers. According to wireshark, my computer is sending ICMP requests and receive responses. After rebooting, ping is starting again...

I have tried to close all apps running, but still those ICMP requests are sent every second. Sometimes the IP address changes but still on Google's server: usually, addresses are something like 216.58.2XX.X

I tried `netstat -ano` but I haven't seen sames IP's addresses.

The solution I found was with PeerBlock and I'm adding the IP addresses to the block list...

Are those requests to Google something normal? What tools can I use to find the program that is sending these requests?

Comment: add `-b` to netstat http://superuser.com/questions/707249/netstat-with-process-name

Comment: do you run Chrome?

Comment: @TeunVink ... that wasn't the IP that was being pinged

Comment: Happened to me too! also I'm on win10, sometimes google force me to enter a capcha because my laptop send request to google! I completely formatted my Laptop and still have the same problem..

Answer (score 2):

Netstat isn't going to show ICMP.

Try installing Microsoft Network Monitor:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/netmon/p/downloads/

Start a capture, filter on ICMP and the destination IP, and you should be able to see the Process Name.